# Examples of functions that do not have a limit as x approaches 2

Tags: calculus, limits

How do I find all the examples of a limit as x approaches 2 that DOES NOT EXIST. 
I know that if there is a vertical asymptote AT 2 then it DNE. What other examples are there?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Another example could be a piecewise function defined on $(-\infty,2)$ and $(2,\infty)$ with a jump between pieces.

Comment: $$\lim\limits_{x\to 2 }\dfrac{1}{x-2} = \text{DNE}$$ however  $$\lim\limits_{x\to 2 }\dfrac{1}{(x-2)^2} = \infty$$

Comment: Okay, thanks, Eul.

Comment: Another example is $f$ keeps osculating when approaches $2$, say $\sin(\frac{1}{x-2})$

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. These are all very helpful.

Comment: An example of a different nature than those given so far is $f(x) = \sqrt{1-x}.$

Answer (score 2):

The function $y = 0$ for $x \lt 2$ and $y = 1$ for $x > 2$ has different limit for left and right.

The function $y = 0$ if $x$ is irrational, and $y = 1$ if $x$ is rational could be considered to have 2 limits.

Answer (score 1):

Inifinite limits are bad examples, I suppose.
If you need a function for which limit **does not exist** while $x \rightarrow 2$, $\sin\frac{1}{x-2}$ should be a good example (try to prove that).